# Looking for geographic information on Veterans with PTSD

Tags: data.gov, medical

Where can I find statistics on veterans with Posttraumatic stress disorder ([PTSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posttraumatic_stress_disorder)).  Along with geographic location and nationality?